# How to recover Ethernet and Wireless drivers on HP pavilion laptop?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, ethernet

I ditched windows completely and installed ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS on my HP pavilion dv series laptop. The wireless and ethernet drivers were working all fine for about one month. Both ethernet and wireless are not working all of a sudden. I dont see anything listed on the additional drivers tab under System and Software settings.

I am not able to connect to LAN using the wire too. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Add the result of `ifconfig` please.